# How to implement TextInputLayout with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput

[image: How to implement TextInputLayout?]

Not long after I started RN, the UI designer asked me to implement this effect, and I was upset

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this example](https://snack.expo.dev/@dsand97/customizedtextinput) using iOS or Android emulators. You can change any style in here because all the styles are customizable and you can use this as a customized text input component in your project. By the way if your UI designer prefers material UI for the project, you can use directly [TextInput](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/text-input.html) component from [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/index.html) library. But it cannot be customized as this example.